# Database Copy Fails, but nothing fishy in the logs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql, sql-server-express

I am attempting to copy a database from a remote server (sql server 2008) to my local machine (running sql server express 2014). Everything looks great, right up until the job fails at "Execute SQL Server Agent Job" with this message:

```
TITLE: Copy Database Wizard
------------------------------

The job failed.  Check the event log on the destination server for details.

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

But I can't find anything in the event log that looks out of place:

```
Date,Source,Severity,Message
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option DB_CHAINING to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option PAGE_VERIFY to CHECKSUM for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option MULTI_USER to ON for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option RECOVERY to FULL for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option READ_WRITE to ON for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option PARAMETERIZATION to SIMPLE for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option TRUSTWORTHY to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option DISABLE_BROKER to ON for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option QUOTED_IDENTIFIER to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option CURSOR_DEFAULT to GLOBAL for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS to ON for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option AUTO_SHRINK to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS to ON for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option AUTO_CLOSE to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option ARITHABORT to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option ANSI_WARNINGS to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option ANSI_PADDING to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option ANSI_NULLS to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Setting database option COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL to 100 for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:47:46,spid61,Unknown,Starting up database 'DotNetNukeCTSI5'.
04/23/2014 15:37:32,spid57,Unknown,AppDomain 2 (mssqlsystemresource.sys[runtime].1) created.
04/23/2014 15:37:31,spid57,Unknown,Common language runtime (CLR) functionality initialized using CLR version v2.0.50727 from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option DB_CHAINING to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option PAGE_VERIFY to CHECKSUM for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option MULTI_USER to ON for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option RECOVERY to FULL for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option READ_WRITE to ON for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option PARAMETERIZATION to SIMPLE for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option TRUSTWORTHY to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option DISABLE_BROKER to ON for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option QUOTED_IDENTIFIER to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option CURSOR_DEFAULT to GLOBAL for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS to ON for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option AUTO_SHRINK to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS to ON for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option AUTO_CLOSE to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option ARITHABORT to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option ANSI_WARNINGS to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option ANSI_PADDING to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option ANSI_NULLS to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT to OFF for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Setting database option COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL to 100 for database DotNetNukeCTSI5.
04/23/2014 15:37:27,spid57,Unknown,Starting up database 'DotNetNukeCTSI5'.
04/23/2014 15:33:27,spid58,Unknown,Using 'xpsqlbot.dll' version '2009.100.1600' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_qv'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
04/23/2014 15:33:27,spid58,Unknown,Attempting to load library 'xpsqlbot.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/23/2014 15:33:27,spid58,Unknown,FILESTREAM: effective level = 0<c/> configured level = 0<c/> file system access share name = 'DWYATTMSSQL'.
04/23/2014 15:33:27,spid58,Unknown,Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 1 to 0. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
04/23/2014 15:33:27,spid58,Unknown,FILESTREAM: effective level = 0<c/> configured level = 0<c/> file system access share name = 'DWYATTMSSQL'.
04/23/2014 15:33:27,spid58,Unknown,Configuration option 'Agent XPs' changed from 0 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
04/23/2014 15:33:27,spid58,Unknown,FILESTREAM: effective level = 0<c/> configured level = 0<c/> file system access share name = 'DWYATTMSSQL'.
04/23/2014 15:33:27,spid58,Unknown,Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 0 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
04/23/2014 15:33:27,,Warning,[396] An idle CPU condition has not been defined - OnIdle job schedules will have no effect
04/23/2014 15:33:27,,Warning,[260] Unable to start mail session (reason: No mail profile defined)
04/23/2014 15:33:27,,Information,[129] SQLAgent$DWYATTMSSQL starting under Windows NT service control
04/23/2014 15:33:27,,Error,[364] The Messenger service has not been started - NetSend notifications will not be sent
04/23/2014 15:33:27,,Information,[432] There are 12 subsystems in the subsystems cache
04/23/2014 15:33:27,,Information,[339] Local computer is KMCNUTT-7 running Windows NT 6.2 (9200)
04/23/2014 15:33:27,,Information,[310] 4 processor(s) and 8067 MB RAM detected
04/23/2014 15:33:27,,Information,[103] NetLib being used by driver is DBNETLIB.DLL; Local host server is KMCNUTT-7\DWYATTMSSQL
04/23/2014 15:33:27,,Information,[102] SQL Server ODBC driver version 10.50.1600
04/23/2014 15:33:27,,Information,[101] SQL Server KMCNUTT-7\DWYATTMSSQL version 10.50.1600 (0 connection limit)
04/23/2014 15:33:27,,Information,[100] Microsoft SQLServerAgent version 10.50.1600.1 ((Unknown) unicode retail build) : Process ID 2008
04/23/2014 15:17:55,spid57,Unknown,Using 'xplog70.dll' version '2009.100.1600' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_msver'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
04/23/2014 15:17:55,spid57,Unknown,Attempting to load library 'xplog70.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/23/2014 15:17:25,Logon,Unknown,Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
04/23/2014 15:17:25,Logon,Unknown,Error: 18456<c/> Severity: 14<c/> State: 8.
04/23/2014 13:13:13,spid52,Unknown,Setting database option PAGE_VERIFY to CHECKSUM for database DNN5.
04/23/2014 13:13:13,spid52,Unknown,Setting database option MULTI_USER to ON for database DNN5.
04/23/2014 13:13:13,spid52,Unknown,Setting database option RECOVERY to FULL for database DNN5.
04/23/2014 13:13:13,spid52,Unknown,Setting database option READ_WRITE to ON for database DNN5.
04/23/2014 13:13:13,spid52,Unknown,Setting database option READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT to OFF for database DNN5.
04/23/2014 13:13:13,spid52,Unknown,Setting database option PARAMETERIZATION to SIMPLE for database DNN5.
04/23/2014 13:13:13,spid52,Unknown,Setting database option DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION to OFF for database DNN5.
04/23/2014 13:13:13,spid52,Unknown,Setting database option AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC to OFF for database DNN5.
04/23/2014 13:13:13,spid52,Unknown,Setting database option DISABLE_BROKER to ON for database DNN5.
04/23/2014 13:13:13,spid52,Unknown,Setting database option RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS to OFF for database DNN5.
04/23/2014 13:13:13,spid52,Unknown,Setting database option QUOTED_IDENTIFIER to OFF for database DNN5.
04/23/2014 13:13:13,spid52,Unknown,Setting database option NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT to OFF for database DNN5.
04/23/2014 13:13:13,spid52,Unknown,Setting database option CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL to OFF for database DNN5.
04/23/2014 13:13:13,spid52,Unknown,Setting database option CURSOR_DEFAULT to GLOBAL for database DNN5.
04/23/2014 13:13:13,spid52,Unknown,Setting database option CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT to OFF for database DNN5.
04/23/2014 13:13:13,spid52,Unknown,Setting database option AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS to ON for database DNN5.
04/23/2014 13:13:13,spid52,Unknown,Setting database option AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS to ON for database DNN5.
04/23/2014 13:13:13,spid52,Unknown,Setting database option AUTO_SHRINK to OFF for database DNN5.
04/23/2014 13:13:13,spid52,Unknown,Setting database option AUTO_CLOSE to OFF for database DNN5.
04/23/2014 13:13:13,spid52,Unknown,Setting database option ARITHABORT to OFF for database DNN5.
04/23/2014 13:13:13,spid52,Unknown,Setting database option ANSI_WARNINGS to OFF for database DNN5.
04/23/2014 13:13:13,spid52,Unknown,Setting database option ANSI_PADDING to OFF for database DNN5.
04/23/2014 13:13:13,spid52,Unknown,Setting database option ANSI_NULLS to OFF for database DNN5.
04/23/2014 13:13:13,spid52,Unknown,Setting database option ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT to OFF for database DNN5.
04/23/2014 13:13:12,spid52,Unknown,Setting database option COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL to 100 for database DNN5.
04/23/2014 13:13:12,spid52,Unknown,Starting up database 'DNN5'.
04/23/2014 13:12:58,spid52,Unknown,Using 'xpstar.dll' version '2009.100.1600' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_instance_regread'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
04/23/2014 13:12:58,spid52,Unknown,Attempting to load library 'xpstar.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
04/23/2014 13:08:49,spid6s,Unknown,Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
```

Answer (score 2):

Check in SQLAGENT.OUT for any related errors.